# How to get the customer name from the observer - magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer

How to get the customer name from the observer - magento 2.
From the event **`customer_register_success`**.

I tried like this but i got an error.

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$customer_id = $customer->getId();
$customer_email = $customer->getEmail();
$customer_name = $customer->getName();
```

I know i can get the name from customer session. what i want here is i want to get the name from **`getEvent`**

Comment: Did you tried $customer->getFirstName(); ?

Comment: Use `$customer->getFirstName()` or `$customer->getLastName()`